# Node, Express 4 - Regex for routing. Alpha or Alphanumeric including hyphen but not purely numeric

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I am trying to build a regex that will match any combination of numerals (0-9), alpha characters and hyphens, but not purely numeric, for use in routing. The simplest example I can give is the following..

```
router.param('slug', function(req, res, next, slug){
     req.slug = slug;
     next();
}
router.get(':slug((?=[a-zA-Z-])[a-zA-Z-\d]+)', function(req, res){
     res.send(req.slug);
}
```

The logic behind the regex has been tested at regex101.com

```
(?=[a-zA-Z-])[a-zA-Z-\\d]+
```

The idea is a positive lookahead to match at least one of a-z, A-Z or -, and then a match for a-z,A-Z,0-9 in any combination.

Except it doesn't work in express. It will match "h", "h-", "h-9", but not with "9-" or "9a". Furthermore, the slug argument in the param call is empty when it does match. I am stumped. I suspect it might be some escaping issue with the regex string?

Here is a reference to the docs for the param call.
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#router.param

Any help appreciated.

Update: I think it has something to do with there being no capture group in the regex..

Another update: the following regex has a capture group, works at regex101.com, but no dice with express...what am I missing here?

```
(\\d*[a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z-\\d]*$)+
```

Third update: express is calling this library https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp, which helpfully points out I should be escaping backslashes. I have edited the post to reflect this. The library itself is turning this

```
(\\d*[a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z-\\d]*$)+
```

into this..

```
^\/(?:((\d(.*)[a-zA-Z-][a-zA-Z-\d](.*)$))+)\/?$
```

Thanks

Comment: `:slug(?=[a-zA-Z-])[a-zA-Z-\d]+` cannot match `:slug9-` because you tell the engine to match a letter or a hyphen after `:slug` with `(?=[a-zA-Z-])`. [`:slug[a-zA-Z-0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/jO0qC1/1) will match all your above values.

Comment: thats why I posted the reference to the docs. The router.param argument is of the format  ':paramname(regex)'. The regex goes in the brackets and gets coverted to paramname inside the router.param call

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

`(?!\d+$)[a-zA-Z-\d]+`

Matches:

`foo-123`
`123-bar`
`foobar`

Does not match:

`123456`